# Mocha doesn't wait until before is done

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I have this method `before` in my mocha tests which prepare the database for testing :

```
before(() => {
        db.User.destroy({where: {}})
            .then(db.User.create({id: 1, username: 'foo', password: 'secret', email: 'foo@local.dev'}))
            .then(db.Post.destroy({where: {}}))
            .then(() => {
                db.Post.create({id: 1, title: 'Foo', markdown: 'Bar', authorId: 1, published: true});
                db.Post.create({id: 2, title: 'Bar', markdown: 'Foo', authorId: 1, published: false});
            })
            .catch(err => console.err(err));
    });
```

My first test is simple :

```
describe('[GET] /posts', () => {
        it('expect to GET all posts', done => {
            chai.request(server)
                .get('/posts')
                .end((err, res) => {
                    expect(err).to.be.null;

                    expect(res).to.have.status(200);
                    expect(res).to.be.json;
                    expect(res.body.length).to.be.equal(2);

                    done();
                });
        });
    });
```

And it doesn't work, my `res.body.length` is equal to 0. The second test :

```
describe('[GET] /posts?published=:bool', () => {
        it('expect to GET all published posts', done => {
            chai.request(server)
                .get('/posts?published=true')
                .end((err, res) => {
                    expect(err).to.be.null;

                    expect(res).to.have.status(200);
                    expect(res).to.be.json;
                    expect(res.body.length).to.be.equal(1);

                    done();
                });
        });
```

Works as expected, the result is here. At the end when I check my database the two posts are here. When I use postman on the address `/posts` it also works as expected...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `before` is running asynchronous code, but you're not telling Mocha that it is.

You can return the promise chain from it (Mocha supports promises as an alternative to the `done` callback):

```
before(() => {
  return db.user.destroy({where: {}})
    .then(db.user.create({id: 1, username: 'foo', password: 'secret', email: 'foo@local.dev'}))
    .then(db.post.destroy({where: {}}))
    .then(() => {
      db.post.create({id: 1, title: 'foo', markdown: 'bar', authorid: 1, published: true});
      db.post.create({id: 2, title: 'bar', markdown: 'foo', authorid: 1, published: false});
    });
});
```

(Mocha will also catch any exceptions so there's no need to add a `.catch`)

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Mocha that you are finished. Mocha has a `done()` callback you can use. But in this case you are better off just returning the promise from your db call:

```
return before(() => {
    db.User.destroy({where: {}})
    // etc ...
})
```

Mocha will wait for the promise to resolve before moving on.